# How do I shorten the repository URL using svn+ssh similar to svnserve -r?

Tags: svn, ssh

In the svnbook, it shows you how to shorten the URL to your repositories when using svnserve as a daemon, using -r like:

```
svnserve -d -r /usr/local/repositories
```

That way, you can refer to the repository you need right after the hostname in the URL without revealing any of the local path (which is /usr/local/repositories/project1):

```
svn checkout svn://host.example.com/project1
```

However, now that I am switching to svn+ssh, I have the local path back in my repository URL:

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://host.example.com/usr/local/repositories/project1
```

Does anyone know how to hide that local path and use a shorter URL as up above, using svn+ssh and WITHOUT using a UNIX soft link on the svn server?  (you still end up with an extra string in the URL if you use a soft link...)

**UPDATE: The solution to this can be found in [the accepted answer over on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/58190/subversion-path-differences-for-svn-and-svnssh) (the green-checked answer).  Yay!**

Comment: I don't know either, but it annoys me that my URLs are so long that they don't fit in the TortoiseSVN drop-downs of repo URLs for things like the Merge. I have to use the repo browser to select any branch, because the MRU history drop-down doesn't have enough space to display it all!  Sorry for venting, this is really a TortoiseSVN issue....

Comment: From what little I've dabbled with SVNServe, I *think* this is only possible with Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The solution to this can be found in [the accepted answer over on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/58190/subversion-path-differences-for-svn-and-svnssh) (the green-checked answer). Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what your asking about but I just use bash aliases to alias the long commands to short ones.

Comment: Good idea, but, I'd like the URL required by the svn server to be as short as possible and not put the burden of aliasing on developers... thank you though!